# Generating a spatial prediction (raster) from a GLMM with a random intercept and a quadratic term

Tags: r, raster, predict, lme4

As indicated in the title, I am trying to generate a predictive raster depicting the relative probability of use. To create a reproducible example, I have used the `MaungaWhau` data from the `maxlike` package. `MaungaWhau` is a `list` that contains two raster layers as well a layer of 1000 locations. So, with these data and packages...

```
library(maxlike)
library(lme4)
data(MaungaWhau)
```

we can make two raster layers, a raster stack, as well as a `SpatialPoints` object.

```
elev <- raster(MaungaWhau$elev, xmn=0, xmx=61, ymn=0, ymx=87) 
precip <- raster(MaungaWhau$precip, xmn=0, xmx=61, ymn=0, ymx=87) 
rs <- stack(elev, precip)

PointDat <- SpatialPoints(MaungaWhau$xy)
```

I then make a new dataframe that contains `IndID`: the unique ID for each individual (AAA - DDD); `Used`: the binary response variable indicating whether the point was used or not (1 or 0, respectively); as well as the `Elev` and `Precip` values for each point from the `SpatialPoints` object.

```
df <- data.frame(IndID = sample(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), 1000, replace = T),
            Used = sample(c(0,1),1000, replace = T),
            Elev = extract(elev, PointDat),
            Precip = extract(precip, PointDat))
head(df); tail(df)

> head(df); tail(df)
  IndID Used      Elev     Precip
1   DDD    0 0.3798393  0.6405494
2   DDD    1 0.8830846  1.1174869
3   AAA    0 1.9282864  0.9641432
4   DDD    0 1.5024634  0.4695881
5   BBB    1 1.3089075 -0.1341483
6   BBB    1 0.5733952  0.6246699
```

I then build a resource selection model (RSF) and specify IndID as a random effect. Notice also, that I included a quadratic term for `Elev`.

```
#Make model
Mod <- glmer(Used ~ Elev + I(Elev^2) + Precip + (1|IndID), family=binomial, data = df, verbos = 1) 
summary(Mod)
```

I am not interested in interpretation given the made up used and available points. My first question is more if a confirmation.  The `raster` package vignette states that "The names in the Raster object should exactly match those expected by the model." In the instance of the quadratic term fit with `I(Elev^2)` am I correct that predict will be 'looking' for `Elev`? This seems to be the case as there in no error associated with `Elev` in the `predict` code below.

Secondly, how do I deal with the random intercept term `(1|IndID)`?  I am interested in marginal predictions and do not need to account for individuals.

With the following code

```
#Change names of layers in raster stack to match model
names(rs) <- c("Elev", "Precip")

Pred <- predict(rs, Mod)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'IndID' not found
```

Is it possible to generate a marginal prediction for the 'typical' individual without passing the `IndID` covariate to the `predict` function?  In other words, I want to ignore the `IndID` term and the associated individual adjustments to the intercept when making the prediction surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `predict` function for lme4 (merMod) objects makes conditional predictions by default.

To make marginal/unconditional predictions, you need to make use of the `re.form` argument.  Your code would look like:

`Pred <- predict(rs, Mod, re.form = NA)`

If you also wanted predictions done on the scale of the response variable, you can use the `type` argument.  See the help page for more details on the available arguments, `?predict.merMod`.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  Wast not sure anyone would see the old question and posted the manual answer, but appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on the `predict` function, generate predictions manually by first making an object of betas of the fixed effects

```
betas <- fixef(Mod)
```

and then generate predictions by multiplying each raster by the respective beta coefficient.

```
Pred <- betas[1] + (elev * betas[2]) + (elev^2 * betas[3]) + (precip * betas[4])
plot(Pred)
```

It is then easy to add or remove the intercept and manually specify a link function (e.g. logit).